# As suit assignes globaly in with statement, python

Tags: python-3.x, with-statement

How can i make the `VAR` in the `as` suit in a `with` statement an un-global variable which is bound to the scope of `with`? In the example below the `f` variable is assigned to after the `with` statement also outside of the `with`:

```
with open("some_text.txt") as f:
    pass

print(f.closed) 
print(f)
```

This returns:

```
>>> True
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='some_text.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

The `as` var is still bound even if i use `with` inside of a function:

```
def longerThan10Chars(*files):
    for my_file in files:
        with open(my_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                if len(line) >= 10:
                    print(line)
    print(f.closed)
```

Here the `f.closed` still prints `True`.

Comment: Are you saying that you want `f` to be unbound after the `with..as` block?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, thats what i have been trying to say.

Comment: You can't. Python has no such fine-grained scopes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python scope boundaries are functions, nothing else. There is no option to make the `with` block a scope; put it in a function if you must make it a separate scope; the `as` target is just another local and won't exist outside of that new function.

Or you can make the name go away after a `with` statement by just deleting the name explicitly:

```
with open("some_text.txt") as f:
    pass

del f
```

Comment: It seems the `as` variable is still bound even inside of a function. Look at my update. So only `del` is going to work.

Comment: He means that you encapsulate all the code where `f` is assigned in a function and then do all the work where you want `f` unassigned outside of the function

Comment: Aaah, Now i got it.

Comment: @student: of course `f` is still defined. The name lives on for the duration of the function. That's what I meant by scopes being bound by a function. The name `f` won't exist *outside* that function.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the binding of `f` do:

```
del locals()['f']
```

You have to do this manually.  The `with...as` block cannot do this for you.

Comment: Why the indirection? `del f` is far more direct; `f` is not dynamic here. And deleting from `locals()` *has no effect on actual locals* because `locals()` is only a reflection of the actual locals array in a function.

Comment: In other words, what you propose will only work at the *global* level, outside of functions, because there `locals()` returns the same dictionary as `globals()`, which is the actual namespace of the module, which can be edited directly.